# Can I buy Zelda: Breath of the Wild on the Nintendo eShop?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild, nintendo-switch, nintendo-eshop

If I have a gift card for the Nintendo eShop, can I use it to buy *The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild*?

Comment: Isn't the game on the eShop?

Comment: The eshop site isnt loading properly for me, so i dont know @Frank

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can. On the eShop screen on your Switch you can scroll to the bottom, choose “redeem code” and enter the code on the back of the card to transfer the value to your account. It is also possible to use a gift card during checkout as well.

You can also go to https://ec.nintendo.com/redeem/#/ to redeem a gift card or other code online.

Further reading:

- [How to Add Funds to Nintendo Switch eShop](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22327/p/897)
- [How to Redeem a Download Code on Nintendo Switch eShop](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22429/p/897/c/186)